# Add order column into query result in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table, called `Table1` that looks like:

```
id|val1|val2|FKId
------------------
 1|val |val | 123
 2|val |val | 123
 3|val |val | 234
 4|val |val | 345
```

I'm using:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
```

I need to add to the result of this query, a column that will contain the order number for each row by FKId. Result that I need looks like:

```
id|val1|val2|FKId |Order
------------------------
 1|val |val | 123 | 1
 2|val |val | 123 | 1
 3|val |val | 234 | 2
 4|val |val | 345 | 3
```

Maybe there is some function in SQL Server to get this?

Comment: Your question is not clear. You want to have one ID called "Order" for each unique value of FkId ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Ranking function `Dense_Rank()` you can get the required order. To know more about `Dense_rank` [**check here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms173825.aspx).

```
SELECT *,
       Dense_Rank()
         OVER (
           PARTITiON BY val1
           ORDER BY fkid) [Order]
FROM   tablename
```

Comment: Thank you. Thats actually what I need.